# How to rename Serenity BDD Reports

Tags: serenity-bdd, thucydides, cucumber-serenity

I'm using Serenity-BDD. When the reports are generated they are named something like "46b29bc63db0f67fe88cfd2a397ea9b2.html".

Is there a way to specify the report name? I have already tried setting serenity.compress.filenames but it did not work.

Thanks,
Lewis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put serenity.compress.filenames=false in your serenity.properties. This should work in version 1.2.1-rc.9

Answer (score 0):

Also use **serenity.project.name** property to set a name of project in report.
([source](http://www.thucydides.info/docs/serenity/#_serenity_system_properties_and_configuration))